# Add Column based on the hive query result using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with column name "Name". I need to look for this name in another table which has 5million rows and get the latest timestamp for the matched value in Name Column and set flag column if we find a row.

Ex. Dataframe DF has following values

```
ID  Name  City
01  XXXX  Austin
02  YYYY  Atlanta
```

Now I need to read Name and add 2 new columns based on the another table query results. Here are the points we need to consider while querying the table
    1. add column for flag as 'Yes' or 'No' if we find a row for matching Name
    2. take latest timestamp from the table where the Name is matching(table may have multiple rows with same name but it will have different timestamps)

Final output dataframe should be like below:

```
ID  Name  City      Flag   timestamp
01  XXXX  Austin    Yes    2018-06-20 00:00:00 
02  YYYY  Atlanta   No
```

Please help me to achieve this in spark scala.

Comment: What did you try by this moment? What problems did you face?

Answer (score 0):

This will depend a little on the spark version you are using, also a little FYI, Dataframes have been deprecated as of version 2.

As far as I can tell, if table one is df1, and table two is df2, you want to filter df2 to the latest row. Next you want a left outer join df2 on df1. You then want to create a "Flag" column, which is set to "yes" if there is a match, and "no" if there's none.

The below code should be something along the lines of what your looking for.

```
val df1 = //Get dataframe one
val df2 = //Get dataframe two

val filteredDf2 = df2.groupBy("name")
                     .agg(max("timestamp").as("timestamp"))
                     .withColumn("Flag", lit("Yes"))

val joinedDfs = df1.join(df1("name") === filteredDf2("name"), "left_outer")
    .select(
             df1("id"),
             df1("name"),
             filteredDf2("Flag"),
             filteredDf2("timestamp")
           )

val replaceNullFlags = joinedDfs.fill("No")
```

This is obviously assuming none of the rest of the data is null.

Comment: Hi VMHY, Thank you for the quick response and I have one question on your answer. We have 5M rows in DF2 and is it wise to get all the data in DF2 or is there any other way to handle this situation like just look at the Name in the hive table and create a column for flag?